# Simulate turning on Sticky Keys in Windows

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events

Using javascript, I am trying to provide users with an option to turn on Sticky Keys.

Manually this can be done by pressing the Shift Key 5 times.

No success with the following. Also tried it with the shiftKeyArg set to true.

```
function stickyKeys() {
var keyboardEvent1 = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
var initMethod = typeof keyboardEvent1.initKeyboardEvent !== 'undefined' ? "initKeyboardEvent" : "initKeyEvent";
keyboardEvent1[initMethod](
"keydown", // event type : keydown, keyup, keypress
true, // bubbles
true, // cancelable
window, // viewArg: should be window
false, // ctrlKeyArg
false, // altKeyArg
false, // shiftKeyArg
false, // metaKeyArg
16,
0
);
var keyboardEvent2 = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
var initMethod = typeof keyboardEvent2.initKeyboardEvent !== 'undefined' ? "initKeyboardEvent" : "initKeyEvent";
keyboardEvent2[initMethod](
"keyup", // event type : keydown, keyup, keypress
true, // bubbles
true, // cancelable
window, // viewArg: should be window
false, // ctrlKeyArg
false, // altKeyArg
false, // shiftKeyArg
false, // metaKeyArg
16,
0
);
document.dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent1);
document.dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent2);
document.dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent1);
document.dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent2);
document.dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent1);
document.dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent2);
document.dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent1);
document.dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent2);
document.dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent1);
document.dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent2);
alert("sticky keys on");
}
```

Comment: Won't work from a Browser (at least a standard one with good security), because all you doing is Triggering an Event in the Browser's JavaScript engine, not in the Win32API that handles all the Windows Events. This is on purpose, for security reasons. You would need a plugin, like ActiveX to or some unstandardised browser that elevates events to the OS.

Comment: I **hope** javascript can never do this ...

Comment: Well Alex it can, just not in typical browsers that are concerned about user security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Won't work from a Browser (at least a standard one with good security), because all you doing is Triggering an Event in the Browser's JavaScript engine, not in the Win32API that handles all the Windows Events.

**This is on purpose, for security reasons.**

You would need a plugin, like ActiveX to or some unstandardised browser that elevates events to the OS.

Comment: Thanks, I won't spend any more time on it.

Comment: No problem man. The reason I know this because I spent hours trying to hack browsers to do similar things, but for Intranet applications on computers I trust. Its difficult to do, but we all know why right :) Keep bad guys out. Good Luck with your app.

Comment: I presume then that there is also no way to know if Sticky Keys are on or off?

Comment: Not unless Windows tells the Browser. That is the only to do it, so you need some kind of service running on the machine, or a way to talk the OS in a trusted way. Breaking out of the Browser is practically impossible. But you can ask the OS using some kind of API, but you need to install in on the machine, there is no other way.